# Oz/Emacs: Browse isn't opening

Tags: emacs, oz

I'm following the book *Concepts, Techniques and Models of Computer Programming*.

The code:

```
{Browse 9*9}
```

When I select the code and select feed region on *OZ* menu, the following happens:

```
{Browse 9*9}
% -------------- accepted
```

But the Browse window not opens. What's wrong?
I installed *emacs 24* and the path for *emacs.exe* with *OZEMACS*.

Comment: Hi, have you installed Tcl? The browser needs Tcl installed

Comment: I installed it, but it still with the same problem. The browse window isn't opening.

Answer (score 1):

quit and restart oz

Also: select FEED BUFFER, you should be OK

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with using EMacs as an editor for Oz @ Mozart. And I ran into issues with being able to use mouse, and being able to launch Mozart Browser window.

I then installed Aquamacs and set the following env variable:
Set [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) as the Mozart emacs editor:
export **OZEMACS**='/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs’

Now, when I run /Applications/Mozart2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/oz it launches Aquamacs where you can see the menu items (top of the monitor) and the Browser window also pops up when using the expression
{Browse 'Hello'}